# Не могу обработать ответ от inline кнопок telegram bot php sdk

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram, бот, sdk

Уже довольно долго мучаюсь, решил зарегистрироваться уже тут.
К сути. Использую библиотеку Telegram Bot PHP SDK. Вот куски кода.

```
<?php
include('vendor/autoload.php'); //Подключаем библиотеку
use Telegram\Bot\Api; 

$telegram = new Api('ххх'); //Устанавливаем токен, полученный у BotFather
$updates = $telegram->getWebhookUpdates(); //Передаем в переменную $updates полную информацию о сообщении пользователя

$text = $updates["message"]["text"]; //Текст сообщения
$chat_id = $updates["message"]["chat"]["id"]; //Уникальный идентификатор пользователя
$name = $updates["message"]["from"]["username"]; //Юзернейм пользователя
$callback_query = $updates['callback_query'];
$data = $callback_query['data'];
...
}elseif ($text == "Work plz") {
        require('keyboard.php');
        $telegram->sendMessage([ 'chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => "Test", 'reply_markup' => $replyMarkup1 ]);
        if ($data == "1") {
            $telegram->sendMessage([ 'chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => "1" ]);
        } else {
            $telegram->sendMessage([ 'chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => "2" ]);}
```

keyboard.php

```
<?php
// Inline keyboard #1
$inline_button0 = array("text"=>"0","callback_data"=>"1");
$inline_button1 = array("text"=>"1","callback_data"=>'/2');
$inline_button1 = array("text"=>"2","callback_data"=>'/3');
$inline_keyboard = [[ $inline_button0,$inline_button1,$inline_button2],
];
$keyboard1=array("inline_keyboard"=>$inline_keyboard);
$replyMarkup1 = json_encode($keyboard1); 
?>
```

Она впринципе (как и всё остальное) работает исправно. Могу ответственно сказать что я пересмотрел все темы тут, и заходил ДАЖЕ на вторую страницу гугла. Что тут может быть не так, хз. Версия не dev, пробовал ставить её, так код переставал работать вообще, делал как тут -> [Как обработать нажатие на кнопку клавиатуры бота, созданном на Telegram Bot API — PHP SDK?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770963/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-telegram-bot-api) толку - 0.

Comment: а ошибка какая? что не так?

Comment: нет никакой ошибки, просто ничего не происходит. А если брать код в данном случае то всегда после сообщения с инлайном будет двойка (которая означает что нихуя не работает (она появляется до того как я жму на саму инлайн кнопку))

Comment: @n.osennij ну что. Ты мне можешь помочь?

Comment: я? нет. я и не говорил, что могу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому понадобится, то вот как я это решил. (я всё таки обновился до dev версии, также у @botfather включил inline mode)
Kod :

```
$inline_id = $updates["callback_query"]["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$data = $updates["callback_query"]["data"];

if (isset($data)) {
    $telegram->sendMessage([ 'chat_id' => $inline_id, 'text' => "Test" ]);
}
```